# How to avoid the pause after each vim -S in Windows

Tags: shell, batch-file, vim

I'm trying to run a vim script on multiple files in Windows.  I created a .bat file that looks like this:

```
vim "myfile" -S vimscript.vim
vim "myfile2" -S vimscript.vim
vim "myfile3" -S vimscript.vim
...
```

The contents of the vimscript are this (it removes trailing tabs and spaces, writes, then quits):

```
:%s/ *$//g
:%s/    *$//g
:wq
```

This works, except after every command vim seemingly executes a PAUSE statement, because I get the message: "Press ENTER or type command to continue."  I'd rather not hold down the return key while I run this on 100+ files; is there a better way?  Using gvim instead of vim doesn't pause but it causes other problems because you're reloading the GUI every time, sometimes causing errors and wasting time.

Comment: I later learned about argdo (:help argdo), which also would have worked without making a batch file (use :nomore beforehand, however).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-s` switch for silent mode.

Comment: Thanks.  Should've checked ":help starting" but I assumed it was a windows thing.